# How to make an image x% bigger in JavaScript (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this ought to be a straightforward thing to do, but I don't see a clear way to do it.

I would like to make it so that when a user hovers the mouse over an image, the image becomes 10% bigger and then returns to its original size when the user moves the mouse away.

I think that I will want to use the jQuery `hover` function, but I don't know what functions to pass into `hover`.

```
$('.resizableImage').hover(makeBigger, returnToOriginalSize);
```

Comment: I considered modifying the CSS, but most anything I can think of turns convoluted very quickly.  I thought that there must be a simple way to do a thing like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery lets you use `+=` and `%`. So those two together will do what you want.

```
$('.resizableImage').hover(makeBigger, returnToOriginalSize);

function makeBigger() {
    $(this).css({height: '+=10%', width: '+=10%'});
}
function returnToOriginalSize() {
    $(this).css({height: "", width: ""});
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/rZaAE/

Comment: This works great!

I wonder if I can use one of the display CSS attributes to keep the other images from being "pushed" off to the side as one image is enlarged...

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon: I'm pretty sure you can. Not sure how off hand though.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with CSS3 tranform property, for example

```
$('.resizableImage').hover(function(){
   $(this).css("transform", "scale(1.1, 1.1)");
}, function(){
   $(this).css("transform", "none");
});
```

Comment: I tried this in Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox 14.  It doesn't work.  Maybe this CSS is not supported in the version I'm running?  I did double-check, using a debugger, that my jQuery selectors are matching elements on the page.

Comment: it would also break if you had `transform` present on that element, since on mouseout it would be removed. You don't need jquery for this effect btw., style `.resizableImage:hover` is enough

Comment: Yep, my bad. Transform is a bit tricky to use, afaik you need to add different tags for different browsers (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Without CSS3 you could simply get original size using `.width()` and `.height()` methods, store it in data attribute(s) and resize. On mouseout just restore the original values.

```
var hoverRatio = 1.1;

$('.resizableImage').hover(function() {
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
    $(this).css({
        width: $(this).width() * hoverRatio,
        height: $(this).height() * hoverRatio 
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).css({
        width: $(this).data('width'),
        height: $(this).data('height')
    });
});​
```

See the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5mnYL/).

Answer (score 1):

You should use stop on the animation also so it doesn't get interrupted when the user moves out before the animation has finsihed

html:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="resizableImage" width="350" height="150" />​
```

js:

```
$('.resizableImage').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ width: "+=10%", height: "+=10%" });
});

$('.resizableImage').mouseleave(function() {
    var x = $(this).attr('width'),
        y = $(this).attr('height');

    $(this).stop().animate({ width: x, height: y });
});
```

​

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tWdAK/1/

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do this with css:

CSS

```
.resizable_img {
    position: relative; // needed for z-index to work
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; // will resize image proportionally

}

.resizable_img:hover {
    width: 120%;
    z-index: 1; // place image on top
}

.img_container {
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible; // stops images being shifted 
    float:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="contents">
    <div class="img_container">
        <img class="resizable_img" src="img.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/yA2WC/3/)

Comment: thanks, worked in a situation where passive page load i.e "/#" was killing the Jquery. Low-tech, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using inline styling, you can omit saving the old values in data and use style attr instead.

```
$('.element').hover(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.attr('style','width:'+el.width() * 1.1 + 'px;height:'+el.height() * 1.1 + 'px;');   
}, function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});​
```