# "Share-to-Facebook" html / php / js

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

When people click my image thumbnail, it enlarges. I would like to create a "share-to-facebook"-function, so they can share the image directly to facebook without having to download it first and then then upload it.

Is it possible to implement it into this following code?

```
//my code
<li  class="span4 gallery-item" data-id="id-1">
    <img class="fancybox" src="img/photoshop2_small.jpg" data-big="img/photoshop2.jpg" />
</li>


// Code facebooks says to implement
<div class="fb-share-button" data-    
href="http://ademphotography.dk/img/photoshop2.jpg" data-layout="button_count">  
</div>
```

Edit: I got my appId and such, and now I am able to both share and like the images, however, the buttons show right below my images.

How do I tweak my code, so that only when I click an image (and it is thereby enlarged) only then there is the opportunity to like/share the image?

```
 <li  class="span4 gallery-item" data-id="id-1">
<img class="fancybox" src="img/photoshop2_small.jpg" data-big="img/photoshop2.jpg" 
/>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://ademphotography.dk/img/photoshop2.jpg" data-width="300"
  data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true">
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you tried using Facebook API? [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#example) Edit: [How to add tutorial](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-add-facebook-share-button-to-your-web-site-pages/)

Comment: Share the code you have tries so far;

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is very easy.

Try this-

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
 <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
 <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
 <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
 <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
 <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
<body>

 <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

 <!-- Your share button code -->
 <div class="fb-share-button" 
  data-href="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" 
  data-layout="button_count">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Find more in **[here in FB Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)**.

Or u can simply try this-

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.org" target="_blank">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Or this way with your app [**registered in FB**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register)-

```
<a name='fb_share' type='button_count' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?appId={YOUR APP ID}&link=<?php the_permalink() ?>' rel='nofollow'>Share</a><script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: I edited my post. 

I am now able to share and like the images, but the buttons for sharing and liking are showing beneath my images. is it possible to make the buttons show only when I click my image? My images enlarges when I click on them.

Comment: Sure, try with jQUery onmouseover event with this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161339/how-to-make-an-image-x-bigger-in-javascript-with-jquery.

Comment: If u find my answer helpful, please accept it. By accepting it will give me and u some reputation in stackoverflow